# Jasper Report jar libraries mandatory to include in java project

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm using JasperReport for this code.

```
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignQuery;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;

    public void printData(String report , String printQuery){
        try{
            jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(report);
            query.setText(printQuery);
            jasperDesign.setQuery(query);
            jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
            jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr,null, databaseHandler.getConnection());
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jp,false);

        }catch (JRException ex) {
            AlertMaker.showException("Exception Occurred ! " , ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

Could anyone help me to tell that which jar libraries file are necessary to include in java project ?
Because including all jar files of `JasperReport` slows down the project performance (these jar lib files are more than 60 )

Answer (score 1):

Basically these are the mandatory jars and remaining you can add as per your requirement.

```
......poi-3.7-20101029.jar        ###support poi 
......commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar 
......commons-collections-3.2.1.jar  ## for Collections
......commons-digester-2.1.jar
......commons-javaflow-20060411.jar
......commons-logging-1.1.1.jar        ### for logging's 
......groovy-all-2.0.1.jar
......iText-2.1.7.js2.jar                ### for pdf
......jcommon-1.0.15.jar            
......jfreechart-1.0.12.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

These are necessary files

- commons-beanutils-1.8.0
- commons-collections-2.1.1
- commons-digester-1.7
- commons-javaflow-20060411
- commons-logging-1.0.4
- groovy-all-1.7.5
- iText-2.1.7
- jasperreports-4.5.0 (any version)
- png-encoder-1.5
- poi-3.7-20101029 (Or poi-3.6)